# Swift share extension fails to load image

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ios12, share-extension

Below is code from a share extension for `iOS` part of a `flutter` app.

I have literally hours of experience working with XCode so please pardon my noob mistakes.
This is the `viewDidLoad` method from my `SLComposeServiceViewController` implementation

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    let content = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem;
    let contentTypeImage = kUTTypeImage as String;
    let contentTypeText = kUTTypeText as String;

    for attachment in content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider] {
        if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeImage) {
            // Verify that the content type is image.
            attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeImage, options: nil) {
                data, error in if error == nil {
                    let url = data as! NSURL
                    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                        // Do something with the image.
                        if(thingGoWrong) {
                            //show error message.
                            self.showErrorMessage(text: "Failed to read image.")
                            return
                        }
                        if (finalOperationSucceeded) {
                            self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Display error dialog for not supported content. Though we should never receive any such thing.
                    self.showErrorMessage(text: error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeText) {
            attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeText, options: nil) {
                data, error in if error == nil {
                    let text = data as! String
                    // do something with the text
                    if (textOpSucceeded) {
                        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text portion of the share extension works as expected, but if I try and send an image to the app. I get this response.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Note:

- The same code runs fine when testing on `iOS 11.4`
- I've tested on `iPhone 6S` simulator `iOS 12.0` where it failed.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried converting the data directly to an UIImage?

Comment: I could try, but the problem is that it fails at `attachment.loadItem`